# subtract first value from each subset of dataframe

Tags: r

I want to subtract the smallest value in each subset of a data frame from each value in that subset i.e.

```
A <- c(1,3,5,6,4,5,6,7,10)
B <- rep(1:4, length.out=length(A))
df <- data.frame(A, B)
df <- df[order(B),]
```

Subtracting would give me:

```
  A B
1 0 1
2 3 1
3 9 1
4 0 2
5 2 2
6 0 3
7 1 3
8 0 4
9 1 4
```

Comment: shouldn't the first column 4th row (4,1) be 0? Also (7,1) should be 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the output you show is not correct. In any case, from what you explain, I think this is what you want. This uses `ave` base function:

```
within(df, { A <- ave(A, B, FUN=function(x) x-min(x))})
  A B
1 0 1
5 3 1
9 9 1
2 0 2
6 2 2
3 0 3
7 1 3
4 0 4
8 1 4
```

Of course there are other alternatives such as `plyr` and `data.table`.

Comment: Wow quick, thanks Arun, first out the block. +1 And yes, my manual maths is pretty poor.

Answer (score 3):

Echoing Arun's comment above, I think your expected output might be off. In any event, you should be able to use can use `tapply` to calculate subsets and then use `match` to line those subsets up with the original values:

```
subs <- tapply(df$A, df$B, min)

df$A <- df$A - subs[match(df$B, names(subs))]

df
  A B
1 0 1
5 3 1
9 9 1
2 0 2
6 2 2
3 0 3
7 1 3
4 0 4
8 1 4
```

Comment: (+1) you could also directly do (in this case): `unlist(tapply(df$A, df$B, function(x) x - min(x)))` (as they are already ordered). In most cases, `ave` is much useful because of this. It gives the output in the same order.

Comment: Thanks both, really handy for me. No doubt will see a lot of use for me.